# Change base url dynamically

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a case where I want to change my url `http://localhost:8080/test` to `http://xxx.localhost:8080/test` on click of a button. On button click it goes to my controller with href "/test". My Spring controller code is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public String test(Model model) {
    try{    
        model.addAttribute("name", "A B C");
        return "sample";
    } catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return "error";
    }
}
```

where sample.jsp is my view name. When the page is loaded I want to change the base url also as stated above.

Comment: Consider using a redirect as described here: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward. If this answers your question, please let me know and I'll add this as the answer.

Comment: Before it gets redirected, it goes to the login screen. I want to maintain the same session. I am using Spring security for user logging. Is there a way to use same session in my test() method?

Comment: Now I am trying the below code but it goes to login screen. I tried using addFlashAttribute but how do I restore the user logging information? @RequestMapping(value = "/tests")
    public String test2(Model model) {
  try{   
   model.addAttribute("test", "test");
   return "sample";
  } catch(Exception e) {
      return "rror";
  }
 }
 
 @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
    public RedirectView test1(Model model) {
  try{ 
   return new RedirectView("http://xxx.localhost:8080/test");
        } catch(Exception e) {
         return new RedirectView("errorUrl");
  }
 }